# Creating tuples of 3s

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, tuples

Hi please how can i make a tuple of 3s out of a 2 lists of tuples of (2s and 1s)

```
list1 = [(2345,7465), (3254,9579)]
list2 = [{'type': '62', 'length': 0.15, 'lanes': 1, 'modes': 'cwt'}, {'type': '62',      'length': 0.16, 'lanes': 1, 'modes': 'cwt'}]
```

The output should look like this:

```
list3 = [(2345,7465,{'type': '62', 'length': 0.15, 'lanes': 1, 'modes': 'cwt'}), (3254,9579,{'type': '62', 'length': 0.16, 'lanes': 1, 'modes': 'cwt'})]
```

Comment: @Martijn Sorry that was a typo, its corrected now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `zip()` to pair up the lists and produce tuples from that:

```
list3 = [(l1[0], l1[1], l2) for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> list1 = [(2345,7465), (3254,9579)]
>>> list2 = [{'type': '62', 'length': 0.15, 'lanes': 1, 'modes': 'cwt'}, {'type': '62',      'length': 0.16, 'lanes': 1, 'modes': 'cwt'}]
>>> [(l1[0], l1[1], l2) for l1, l2 in zip(list1, list2)]
[(2345, 7465, {'lanes': 1, 'length': 0.15, 'type': '62', 'modes': 'cwt'}), (3254, 9579, {'lanes': 1, 'length': 0.16, 'type': '62', 'modes': 'cwt'})]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on index using list comprehension:

```
[ list1[i1]+(list2[i1],) for i1 in range(len(list1))]
```

Output:

```
[(2345, 7465, {'lanes': 1, 'length': 0.15, 'type': '62', 'modes': 'cwt'}), (3254, 9579, {'lanes': 1, 'length': 0.16, 'type': '62', 'modes': 'cwt'})]
```